# Bootstrap 4 angular 5 navbar links not getting aligned to right

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

[image]I am trying to create an application with bootstrap 4 and angular 5 first time, but the navbar links that are aligned to right are getting aligned to left.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand abs" href="#">Navbar 1</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#myAlert" data-toggle="collapse">Link</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried multiple options but output is not getting corrected.Hence request help to get link: **About** right aligned.

Comment: I put your code into a codepen and everything's aligned correctly. Is there some stylesheet apart from bootstrap that could be interfering? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwwRpy

Comment: no there is no other style other than bootstrap, i will try to create a live example , but the code is part of component of angular and that is added to app.component.html

Comment: yes you were right there was another css for older version of bootstrap was included in app.component.css, i realized it when i created an online example.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y524up

Comment: If you want the About item to be on the right using Angular & bootstrap it works for me: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8xkv1d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand abs" href="#">Navbar 1</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar" style="justify-content:flex-end">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#myAlert" data-toggle="collapse">Link</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">About</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
```